What is causing the AWS SecurityTokenServiceClient AssumeRoleAsync timeout?
Our application is assuming a role via AWS's SecurityTokenServiceClient instance.
First, we instantiate a new instance of AmazonSecurityTokenServiceClient with the necessary parameters, construct a new AssumeRoleRequest, and then perform the AssumeRoleAsync call on the client. The issue is that the AssumeRoleAsync call is timing out after a while and does not seem to respond successfully with any subsequent calls.
Below is a sample of our implementation,
using (var client = new Amazon.SecurityToken.AmazonSecurityTokenServiceClient("SomeKey", "SomeSecret", "SomeRegion"))
{
    var assumeRoleRequest = new AssumeRoleRequest
    {
        RoleSessionName = "SomeSessionName",
        RoleArn = "SomeRoleArn",

    };
    var assumeRoleResponse = await client.AssumeRoleAsync(assumeRoleRequest); //Timeout experienced
}

Could it be that the AssumeRoleRequest.RoleSessionName need to be unique for each call? Or any other idea on why timeouts would occur?

Do you catch exceptions for this request? It probably is TaskCancelledException for 'real' request timeout due to network conditions, slow response from STS etc. Otherwise, if it's misconfiguration of your request or policies in your account, your STS client or the AssumeRoleAsync() request itself should throw an exception with more detailed information. RoleSessionName is recommended to be unique for identification purposes only but it's not a requirement but it must be created with upper- and lower-case alphanumeric characters with no spaces and the following characters: =,.@-_
